# Web Service that pulls data from an oracle database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, web-services, asmx

I am trying to make a web service so that it pulls aliquot_IDs based on project number from an Aliquot table sitting in an Oracle database? For example, for project number 123 (XYZ), it should extract all the aliquots for project XYZ.
I just need to see how I can organize the code and if it is accurate.

Below is the .asmx file I created

Aliquot.asmx

```
 <%@ WebService Language="vb" Codebehind="Aliquot.asmx.vb" Class="Aliquot" %>

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types
Imports System.Data.OracleClient

<WebService([Namespace]:="http://bioservices.com/webservices/")> _
Public Class Aliquot
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod(Description:="Get All Aliquot_IDs from Aliquot table", EnableSession:=False)> _
Public Function GetAliquotID() As DataSet
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select AliquotID, Name From Aliquots", conn)

    Dim AliquotDS As DataSet = New DataSet()
    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    adapter.Fill(AliquotDS, "Aliquots")
    Return AliquotDS

End Function
Public Sub CreateOracleConnection()
    Dim ConnectionString As String = _
    "Data Source=Oracle8i; Integrated Security=yes"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Console.WriteLine("ServerVersion: " + connection.ServerVersion _
                          + ControlChars.NewLine + "DataSource: " + connection.DataSource)
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is your question? Does this work? If not what error do you get?

Comment: Your connection string is wrong, - the Data Source is generally an entry in your TNSNAMES file and you also need a User ID and a Password parameters. Also, you cannot use SqlCommand as it's for SQL/Server. Use OracleCommand instead.

Comment: Thank you, My question is How to create a web service so that it pulls aliquot_IDs based on project number from an Aliquot table sitting in an Oracle database? For example, for project number 123 (XYZ), it should extract all the aliquots for project XYZ. The error I am getting is the following:  Compiler Error Message: BC30108: 'Content' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.
Source Error:

Line 18:         Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select AliquotID, Name From Aliquots", Content)

Comment: I don't see `Content` anywhere in the code you're posting.  Sounds like you have a lot of learning to do - writing web services, connecting to databases, writing queries.  SO is not a code-writing service - you'll need to do the research and come back with _specific_ questions.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: BC30108: 'Content' is a type and cannot be used as an expression. Source Error: Line 18: Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select AliquotID, Name From Aliquots", Conn)

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5 that's why I am using the .ASMX